# A hibernate criteria query where values equal properties with an entity's collection field

Tags: hibernate, subquery, criteria, detachedcriteria

How to get all employees named "John Smith" using the hibernate criteria approach?

`@Entity
    public class Name{
        private long id;
        private String title
        private String first;
        private String last;
        private String suffix;
        @OneToMany(mappedby = "name")
        private Set<Employee> employees;
    }`

`@Entity
    public class Employee{
        private long id;
        private int age;
        private Date dateStarted;
        private String highestEducationCompleted;
        @ManyToOne
        private Name name;
    }`

I attempted the following and got a `NullPointerException` in the subquery processing. It seems like the hibernate engine requires projections subqueries which may cause this approach not to work for this use case anyway:

`DetachedCriteria getNames = new DetachedCriteria(Name.class);
    getNames.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("first", "John"),     Restrictions.eq("last", "Smith")));
    Criteria getEmployees = getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);
    getEmployees.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("names", getNames);
    getEmployees.list();`

What is a better way to get this done using the hibernate criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate folks have known about this issue at least since 2005 and have largely ignored it. See an original bug report here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-993